# Magento 2.1 Product Admin Image Upload

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, product-images

I am trying to apply images to those products that are missing them in my development magento 2.1 system.
The initial product data was imported from a magento 1.9.2 system, and since that import, new products have been created in Magento 2.
All existing products (imported) have their respective images applied and working fine in both admin and frontend.

When I try to add a new image to a new product, the image seems to upload to the system fine (it appears on the product admin page while setting base, small and thumb roles for the image.

After I click save on the product though, that image no longer appears in the admin pages (product listing, or edit product pages), nor does it appear on the front end product pages?

I have tried clearing and flushing the cache (although cache is disabled on this dev site currently), tried reindexing everything, checked folder permissions etc.

I am scared to try and run...

```
magento catalog:image:resize
```

...for fear of it taking days to complete, based on what I have read in many other threads. For someone else, it took 12 hours for 6000 products, and I have 36000 products!!!

Not sure why this is not working as expected?

Comment: Use migration for magento 1.9 to magento2

Comment: The site is in the middle of the migration process (stage 1 done, stage 2 to be completed soon). During this time, new products have been added to the original system, but they will not be synced over to the new system in migration stage 2, so I need to get the image data assigned to each product. The import of images is supposed to work as per the devdocs, but it does not.